# Querying of Members of a Cooperative by using any search term and the cooperative id in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

i am new to hibernate search and have this issue, i want to search for members in a particular cooperative using any of firstname, middlename, lastname, username together with the cooperative id in hibernate search, the search is returning members that matches any of the search term without considering the cooperative id.

Your help with the above problem is highly appreciated, i am still a novice with hibernate search and this is really taking my time.

Please see code sample below:

```
public List<MemberProfile> searchForMember(String memberSearchTerm, int cooperativeId, int pageNumber, int pageSize) throws Exception {
        HibernateDataAccess dao = new HibernateDataAccess();
        List<MemberProfile> members = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            dao.startOperation();

            Cooperative cooperative = (Cooperative) dao.searchObject(Cooperative.class, cooperativeId);

            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(dao.getSession());
            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MemberProfile.class).get();

            org.apache.lucene.search.Query cooperativeQuery = qb
                    .keyword()
                    .onField("cooperative.cooperativeName")
                    .matching(cooperative.getCooperativeName())
                    .createQuery();

            org.apache.lucene.search.Query memberQuery = qb
                    .keyword()
                    .onFields("username", "firstName", "middleName",
                            "lastName", "phoneNumber", "emailAddress")
                    .matching(memberSearchTerm)
                    .createQuery();

            org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.bool()
                    .must(cooperativeQuery)
                    .must(memberQuery)
                    .createQuery();

            Query query = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, MemberProfile.class)
                    .setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                    .setMaxResults(pageSize);
            members = query.getResultList();

            dao.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            dao.rollback();
            logger.error("error thrown - ", ex);
            throw new Exception(ex);
        } finally {
            dao.closeSession();
        }
        return members;
    }
```

Comment: Please see code sample below:

Comment: can you add a snippet of your code.It will be easy to answer if you add that

Comment: The code snippet is below my question, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The query seems correct. My best guess is that there is some common word in the cooperative name (say "coop" or "cooperative"), and the query on the cooperative name ends up matching a lot of different cooperatives.

Since you have the ID as an input, you will be better off running a query on cooperative ID directly.

First, make sure to include the cooperative ID in your `@IndexedEmbedded`:

```java
public class MemberProfile {

   // ...

   @ManyToOne
   @IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true) // Change this
   private Cooperative cooperative;

   // ...

}
```

Then reindex your data.

Then change this part of your code:

```java
            Cooperative cooperative = (Cooperative) dao.searchObject(Cooperative.class, cooperativeId);

            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(dao.getSession());
            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MemberProfile.class).get();

            org.apache.lucene.search.Query cooperativeQuery = qb
                    .keyword()
                    .onField("cooperative.cooperativeName")
                    .matching(cooperative.getCooperativeName())
                    .createQuery();
```

to this:

```java
            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(dao.getSession());
            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MemberProfile.class).get();

            org.apache.lucene.search.Query cooperativeQuery = qb
                    .keyword()
                    .onField("cooperative.id")
                    .matching(cooperativeId)
                    .createQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i have done as you said, what is happening now is that i get an empty array as the result set.  See some code in my MemberProfile object below: 
public class MemberProfile  implements java.io.Serializable {
     DocumentId
     private int id;
     private Long version;
     private Bank bank;
     @IndexedEmbedded
     private Cooperative cooperative;

Comment: You can't paste code in comments. Please update your question by adding new code to the bottom. Please also describe the search parameters (cooperative ID and search terms) and the relevant dataset (the member you expect match, its cooperative ID, its userName, firstName, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, i had to set Analyze.YES to Analyze.NO on the Cooperative entity and reindexed my entity as shown below:
Thanks so much @yrodiere, i am very grateful for your help.

@Indexed
public class Cooperative  implements java.io.Serializable {

```
 @DocumentId
 private int id;
 private Long version;
 private CooperativeIndustry cooperativeIndustry;
 private CurrencyType currencyType;
 private FrequencyOfContribution frequencyOfContribution;
 private State state;
 private String cooperativeCode;
 @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
```